# What is the greatest number of free kick goals scored by a player in professional football?

Tags: football, trivia

Which player has the most goals from free kicks in professional football history?

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Brazilian player [Juninho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juninho_Pernambucano). His Wikipedia article, citing three separate sources, states:

> Noted for his bending free kicks, he is widely considered to be the greatest free kick-taker of all time **and holds the record for the highest number of goals scored through free kicks with 75**.

Google brings up multiple sources, such as [this one](https://thefootballfaithful.com/players-most-free-kicks-scored-football-history/), that credit him with 77 free-kick goals. Every article I can find, however, agrees that Juninho holds the record, regardless of what his total is.